# 3D solid file layers to three.js json

Tags: html, 3d, three.js, cad

First of all: I'm a skilled developer and a total noob of 3D solid files/drawing.
I started playing with webgl and three.js. My task is to port a solid 3D file(i.e. STEP/IGES) to a web page(a sort of a cad viewer).

I started from this example:
http://www.johannes-raida.de/jnetcad/RadialEngine.htm

I want to obtain something like the above link with
a navigation tree and hide/show layers functionality.

The above link has sever json file, one for layer.

I want to obtain: **a threejs-json file for each layer** to get the hide/show functionality.

Now, I have a solid file (STEP format: .STP). That file contains layers. I want to obtain a json(three.js) file for each layer.

Questions are:

- **how to export to threejs-json using free software?** I read that the best method could be: STEP > Wavefront OBJ [using freecad?] > treejs-json [using blender?]
  Does the collada format is better than obj?
- **Shoud I have to manually export each single layer to json?**
- **Is there an utility out there to generate all the layers(separated files)**(json-threejs format) from a 3d file?

Answer (score 2):

So, I did it by myself.
Three.js is a great library but it requires some 3d skills.

Here are my answers:

**how to export to threejs-json using free software?**

Well, my suggestion is to convert your solid file to DAE, use anything you want.
Then open DAE with Blender and use the exporter script of three.js:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

**Shoud I have to manually export each single layer to json?**

No, the 3D file has all the informations about layers. So you can use a single file.

**Is there an utility out there to generate all the layers?**

I don't have found somethig good out there. 
If you want to create single layers, you can split the json file created with blender.